# How to convert the SQL query into LINQ?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I am new to LINQ. Can anyone please help me convert the following SQL query to LINQ?

```
SELECT 
   Date,ShiftName,Max(Score) AS Score, 1 AS IsPreferred  
FROM 
   Temp_Nurse_Fill_RequestNumbers 
group by 
   ShiftName,date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from t in Temp_Nurse_Fill_RequestNumbers 
group by t.ShiftName, t.date
into g 
select new 
{
   Date = g.date,
   Score = (from tt in g select tt.Score).max
   IsPreferred = 1
};
```

Comment: hi MGA thanks for u r help. Can u please give me the same linq query in vb.net then it is very usefull for me plz...

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, how about something like this (this is C#, I presume it is trivial to convert)

```
temps
    .GroupBy(x => new {x.ShiftName, x.Date})
    .Select(g => new TempNurseProjection
        {
            Date = g.Key.Date,
            ShiftName = g.Key.ShiftName,
            MaxScore = g.Max(q => q.Score),
            IsPreferred = true
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for convenience

```
tems.
    GroupBy(Function(x) New With { x.ShiftName, x.Date }).
    Select(Function(g) New TempNurseProjection With {
        .Date = g.Key.Date,
        .ShiftName = g.Key.ShiftName,
        .MaxScore = g.Max(Function(q) q.Score),
        .IsPreferred = True
    })
```

**EDIT**

Sorry didn't noticed that the final projection is not anonymous but named type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool called LINQPad.

> Tired of querying in antiquated SQL?
>   Well, you don't have to!  LINQPad lets you interactively query databases in a modern query language: LINQ.  Kiss goodbye to SQL Management Studio!
>   ... LINQPad is also a great way to learn LINQ: it comes loaded with 500 examples from the book, C# 4.0 in a Nutshell.  There's no better way to experience the coolness of LINQ and functional programming.

[LINQPad Website](http://www.linqpad.net/)

**hope this helps**