# Convert SQL query to LINQ-To-SQL in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Convert the below Sql Query into LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426208/how-to-convert-the-below-sql-query-into-linq)

I am new to Linq can any one please help me to convert the following sql query to Linq using VB.Net:

```
SELECT 
   Date,ShiftName,Max(Score) AS Score, 1 AS IsPreferred  
FROM 
   Temp_Nurse_Fill_RequestNumbers 
group by 
   ShiftName,date
```